# Docker Volumes + multiple folders

Tags: docker, zabbix

I want to use the image Zabbix/Zabbix-snmptraps
it creates two mount points:

`/var/lib/zabbix/snmptraps`

`/var/lib/zabbix/mibs`

it creates two volumes automatically

I can put both volumes in one volume using the following command:

> docker volume create zabbix-snmptraps-volume
>
> docker run -it -d --name zabbix-snmp --mount type=volume, >source=zabbix-snmptraps-volume,destination=/var/lib/zabbix/snmptraps,destination=/var/lib/zabbix/mibs zabbix/zabbix-snmptraps

or my thoughts are stupid and you can’t do that

Thanks!!

Comment: What happens if you try?  What effect are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

No , You can't.

see the ref [docker-volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can do this. Docker volumes are created from a single source to my knowledge. Is there a specific reason why you want to combine multiple volumes into one?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply

I just wanted to have fewer folders. Some images create many folders in the Volume directory.
So that the name is not a set of characters, but a name that is understandable to a person.
Then I will create named volumes for each folder